# How to dump firmware from R5F71424 MCU

Tags: debugging, firmware, hardware, memory-dump

I've read through the [Renesas SH7417 family manual](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/doc/products/mpumcu/001/rej09b0230_sh7147hm.pdf?key=7ec46b48f36cbf2a036fc6d774223cd7) and I don't see how to extract the firmware.

It has a limited boot mode that only allows writing to the MCU.

Any pointers or ideas would be helpful.